# Convert Time in SQL not to have millisecond

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a `datetime` column in my table but I need to separate it into date and time so here's what I've done so far.

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), [timeStamp], 103) AS date, CONVERT(TIME, [timestamp]) AS time
```

But the problem is, I'm having milliseconds in the time column (eg. 23:39:55.0000000) so how can I do to have just hour:minute:second only?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can convert to [`DATE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630352(v=sql.105).aspx) and [`TIME(0)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677243(v=sql.105).aspx).

```
CONVERT(DATE, [timeStamp]) AS date, CONVERT(TIME(0), [timeStamp]) AS time
```

Comment: @YeMyatAung If you need the date as a string with a specific format you should use what you had in the question for the date part.